# bootstrap datepicker не обновляет дату

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

Почему не меняется дата после нажатия на кнопку `смена даты`
В чем проблема ?

```js
$('#sandbox-container').datepicker({
  inline: true,
  sideBySide: true,
  startDate: new Date(),
  format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
});

$('.change-date').click(function() {
  $('#sandbox-container')
    .datepicker('setDate', new Date('2017-01-31'))
    .datepicker('update');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="sandbox-container">
</div>
<button class="change-date">смена даты</button>
```

Comment: `setDate` может надо, а не `setValue` ?

Comment: @teran тоже самое, я даже изменил пример кода

Comment: какие-то проблемы с приведением к локальному времени, когда передаешь дату. Если передавать строку `.datepicker('setDate', '31-01-2017')` то все работает